# Менять цвет текста в поле для ввода comboBox на красный, если введённый текст не является одним из элементов comboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: Вот так должно выдавать]

Как поменять цвет текста в поле для ввода комбобокса на красный, если введённый текст не является одним из элементов комбобокса (учитывать регистр букв). В противном случае, менять цвет текста на чёрный.

```
    private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
            comboBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
       
    }
```

Остановился на этом, не знаю как написать условие

Comment: Попробовал костыль drawitem но все равно меняется frontcolor и в списке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычный Linq запрос в коллекцию. Если не содержит - сменить цвет.

```
private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!comboBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Contains(comboBox1.Text, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        comboBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    else
        comboBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
}
```

`ForeColor` поменяет цвет и выпадающем списке. Чтобы это исправить, придется втыкать костыль в обработчике **DrawItem**.

```
private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox box = (ComboBox)sender;
    e.DrawBackground();
    Brush brush = Brushes.Black;
    string text = box.Items[e.Index].ToString();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, box.Font, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
}
```

Тогда цвет текста будет меняться только в поле ввода.

Comment: Не получается, если совпадает с итемом комбобокса, то меняет все итемы из выпадающего на красный цвет, а нужно, чтоб при полном совпадении цвет поля для ввода изменялся на черный

Comment: @ВикторИванов добавил else, вы точно бы не догадались это сделать? Насколько это сложно выглядит?

Comment: Только учусь, не сразу догадался)

Comment: @ВикторИванов `ForeColor` поменяет цвет и выпадающем списке. Чтобы это исправить, придется втыкать костыль в обработчике DrawItem.

Comment: Спасибо и на этом, постараюсь сделать этот костыль

Comment: @ВикторИванов уже сделал, обновите страницу.

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли)